# Looking for the simplest possible template

Tags: titles

I want to edit a very simple document. A title at the upper left on the first page. No date, no author, and a text right after the title.

I could achieve positioning the text at the upper left corner using the titling package. But once I do it I cannot:

1. Set the text to appear right after the title

   Set the title to bold

   Align the body text to the left, following the title

I used this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Simple title}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}   % This is your set screw
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

Body text.
\end{document}
```

The result was the title at the upper left corner of the first page. The text staring in the second page.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to overthink stuff.

[image: danTitle]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\noindent {\bfseries\LARGE The Journey of Karl Koala\par}
\bigskip\noindent
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You get a single page for your title because you use `titlingpage`. If you drop this environment, simply use `\pretitle` and `\posttitle`, you can achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{\textbf{Simple title}}
\date{}
\author{}
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{flushleft}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

    Body text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem seems to be conceptual. I used the following code and that was what I needed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,paper=a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}% I used this line to be sure what I wanted as margins, later I removed the showframe parameter

\begin{document}

\part*{Section title} 
\subsection*{Subtitle}

I've used both part and subsection, but subsection would be enough for my purpose

\end{document}
```